# How to identify Nouns in string and capitalize them?

Tags: python, nlp, text-processing

I have simple plain text in lower case and no punctuation. Is there any library which can help changing the upper case like where Nouns are or where required? Like names after Mr. and so.? Any solution or guiding hint can be very helpful.
for example:
in english language in English .. in plain text, at several places are names. and several names needed to be capitalized. like

```
mr. john is living in canada
```

to

```
Mr. John is living in Canada
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround using [`nltk`](https://www.nltk.org/) library to identify nouns using `pos_tag` feature:

```
#Import nltk modules

import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tag import pos_tag

text = "mr. john is living in canada"

#Define a function to extract nouns from the string

def ExtractNoun(sentence):
    sentence = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    sentence = nltk.pos_tag(sentence)
    return sentence

sent = ExtractNoun(text)

#This will return a tuple of tokens and tags

print(sent)
[('mr.', 'NN'), ('john', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('living', 'VBG'), ('in', 'IN'), ('canada', 'NN')]

#Create a list of nouns

nn = [i[0] for i in sent if i[1] == 'NN']

#Capitalize the nouns which are matching with the list

text_cap = " ".join([x.capitalize() if x in nn else x for x in text.split()])
print(text_cap)

'Mr. John is living in Canada'
```

Hope this works!!